# OpenGL padding and miplevels when streaming texture atlas parts

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-atlas

I have a texture atlas, only few pieces of it changes and this happens sometimes,so not everyframe

**My PBO strategy:**

- create a PBO of the size of the atlas
- use glMapBufferRange to specify a memory area inside PBO large enough to accomodate all pixels of the tiles that changes
- use glUnmapBuffer
- use glTexSubImage2D for each tile (using correct offset instead of pointer for the currently bound PBO)

**Question number 1)**

Is there any direct mapping between PBO and Texture Object?
so assume this is the atlas

[image: Texture atlas]

Can I happily upload following data into the PBO ?

[image: Array of pixels]

**Question number 2)**

Assume

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
```

What about alignment of subimages? Should I assume that each image is aligned to the ATLAS (1), or should I assume that each image is aligned to a texture of same size (2)?

[image: alignment picture]

**Assuming 1**:
In the picture above you can see red vertical lines (4 bytes columns) that are referred to texture ATLAS, orange area should be padding bytes I have to add to the subimage before each row of pixels.

**Assuming 2**:
There will be no padding before each pixel row, but there will be some padding after each pixel row (like in ordinary textures that are RGB8 and not a power of 2 as size)

**Question number 3)**

How should I update miplevels? Have I to create and update all miplevels manually or there is a efficient way to let OpenGL update mipmap levels on its own?

Comment: As for the mipmapping question, you can either specify them yourself by setting the proper level on `glTexSubImage` or you can call `glGenerateMipmap` once you are done updating to generate the whole mip chain. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml